# Seeming paradox regarding conservation of angular momentum

Tags: angular-momentum

Two equal mass astronauts in space are holding hands: one's right hand with the other's left hand and left with right. They are facing each other and **are stationary**. Astronaut A pulls with her right hand B's left hand toward herself. While at the same time, B pulls on A using her right hand to draw A's left hand toward herself.The two astronauts begin to rotate about a central axis passing through the space between them. 
I know that angular momentum conservation is true at all times however, in this situation i am unable to explain it. The rotation of the astronauts implies that initially though $\vec L$ was zero about the central axis; that's not the case anymore. How do i resolve this? Is there a fault regarding the non-rigidity of the system?

Comment: You cannot pull the others hand without the others hand pulling you. Newton's third law.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that. However, not considering the rigid system, and assuming that each astronaut 'lets' the other twist her about her own axis...then?

Answer (score 1):

> The two astronaut begin to rotate about a central axis passing through the space between them.

That's the part you're getting wrong.  There's no reason for this to happen.  The astronauts could (using some other method) momentarily transfer angular momentum between each other, so that one spins clockwise while the other spins counterclockwise, for example.  But if they want to keep holding hands, they would have to stop their spins shortly thereafter.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The problem was found on an article where it was stated that the two astronauts rotate about the central axis. I have lost the said article and don't know the conclusion. But would it be wrong to say that the two astronauts were to continue their rotation about the central axis, holding hands....or is that line of thinking wrong because of the violation of conservation of angular momentum?

Comment: That line of thinking is wrong because it would violate conservation of angular momentum.  They could make each other spin in opposite directions and then let go, but their *total* angular momentum has to remain zero.

Comment: hmm...thank you. I see the reason but can't get the feel for it.

Comment: One more question to that effect: Is it possible that this is similar to the falling cat problem?

Comment: @Entangled_Particle A falling cat can store angular momentum by swinging its tail.

Comment: @rob Angular momentum of a falling cat remains zero at all times.

Comment: The *total* angular momentum remains zero.  But the cat can give some angular momentum to its tail, as long as its body then gets an equal and opposite amount of angular momentum.

Comment: Yes, i agree. *total* angular momentum remains zero for a falling cat but angular momentum can be stored in it's tail, provided an equal and opposite angular momentum appears somewhere in the rest of the body. However, i can't comprehend how this relates the situation that i have mentioned. Or, does it at all?

Comment: Well, this conversation has turned into a bit of a mess, so I'm not sure what you're referring to.  But you mentioned the "falling cat" situation.  In principle, a cat could store angular momentum in its tail so that its body rotates oppositely until such time as its paws are pointing downward, thus landing on its feet despite the fact that angular momentum was conserved.  In practice, this is evidently [not quite how it works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_cat_problem#Solution).  But the problem does seem very analogous to your original question...

Comment: Here is a nice video of a cat falling with an explanation. youtube.com/watch?v=RtWbpyjJqrU

Comment: @Mike Just to sum it up a bit: If it were a rigid system, there would be no such rotation about a central axis possible, yes? For a system that can twist and turn, I don't know what to say.

Answer (score 0):

> Astronaut A pulls with her right hand B's left hand toward herself. While at the same time, B pulls on A using her right hand to draw A's left hand toward herself.

Notice that both astronauts move closer to each other on both sides, since both pull with their right hands and are pulled by their left hands. Assuming rigid (and symmetric and identical) astronauts, they don't twist or spin, but simply accelerate into each other face to face. A generates a clockwise torque on B, but the reaction force causes a counterclockwise torque on A. Meanwhile B is generating a clockwise torque on A (canceling out the CCW torque A generates by pulling B) and *that* reaction generates a counterclockwise torque on B, canceling out the original CW torque caused by A's pull. Each astronaut experiences a net zero torque, and thus no net change in angular momentum: and if the angular momentum of each astronaut stays the same, then so does the angular momentum of the entire system.

Comment: You're saying that since the two forces on each pair of hands form action-reaction pair, so there's no net torque and there by no change in angular momentum which remains zero. All that happens is that the two astronauts move closer. Hmm..I had thought on the same lines but I remember distinctly that the article described rotation occurring. Don't get me wrong. I want to come to a clear understanding even if that means I had the initial situation entirely wrong. I just have lingering doubts. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

With the astronauts, there are two general ways to contribute to the angular motion of the system: the motion of the astronaut's center of mass around the axis in question, and the spin of the astronaut around their own center of mass.

So it's quite possible for the system to begin at rest ($L=0$), and through internal forces start things spinning.  The astronauts may start moving around this axis clockwise with some angular momentum $L$.  If so, then they will be rotating counterclockwise with some angular momentum $-L$.  The total momentum is conserved.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes,I tried resolving my doubt this way. There has to be an equal and opposite angular momentum contribution from the motion of the astronauts, perhaps about their own axis... But I was not sure how this would happen if they keep holding there hands.

Comment: If they remain holding hands (making the spin and rotation rate identical in the long term), then they can't be rotating as a group around the central axis.  The first pull will cause rotation and spin as they approach.  But if the hands don't release then both rotation and spin will stop.